# SQL join ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have two different models one called numbers which is structured like this

```
t.string :number
t.date :texted
t.integer :times
t.timestamps
```

and one called Users (I only included the relevant portion)

```
  t.string :phone_number
  t.timestamps
```

What I need to do is grab all numbers that the texted date is more than 2 weeks ago and times is less than 4 and that t.string :number is not equal to any t.string :phone_number in the users table. Do I need to do some sort of sql join to accomplish this?

This is what I have so far:

```
numbers = Onumber.where("texted <= ? AND times<=4",2.week.ago.utc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a `left join` would be more suitable here:

```
Onumber.joins(
  'left join users on onumbers.number = users.phone_number'
).where(
  'users.phone_number is null and onumber.times <= 4 and onumber.texted < ?', 2.weeks.ago.utc
)
```

This will give you all the numbers not in `users.phone_number`, `texted` with `times` value less than or equal to 4.